# Charset issue from local to remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem of charset.
On localhost everything works fine, but now on remote server I see strange characters replacing others like à or è. I have read it's a charset issue and I think the problem can be my php.ini (I can't edit it).
To solve it I've tried many things:
I've set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

on html,

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

on php,

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

on my .htaccess file,
if I use utf8_encode on strings letters are replaced by ã or similar, if I leave it without doing anything letters are �
There is another way to solve this problem that I have not found yet?

Sorry, I forgot to say it: strings are retrieved from another site by a file_get_contents (I'm using a Yandex API)

Here's some code:

```
$yandex = 'https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice.json/lookup?key=my_api_key&lang=it-it&text=attualità';

// get json from this page
$object = json_decode(file_get_contents($yandex));
$syns_array = array();
$type = '';
// if the word exists
if (!empty($object->def) && $object->def != FALSE && $object->def != NULL) 
{
    $type = $object->def[0]->tr[0]->pos;
    $rows = $object->def[0]->tr;
    // if there're synonyms
    if (!empty($rows) && $rows != FALSE && $rows != NULL) 
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            array_push($syns_array, $row->text);
            // if there're more rows with syns
            if (!empty($row->syn) && $row->syn !== FALSE && $row->syn !== NULL) 
            {
                foreach ($row->syn as $syns_obj) 
                {
                    array_push($syns_array, $syns_obj->text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// I echo my synonyms from the array
foreach($syns_array as $syn) {
    echo $syn;
}
```

Comment: How did you retrieve those characters? Are they hard-coded in the file or they are retrieved from a database? Ciao.

Comment: Check that the files are saved in utf-8... how do you transfer the files to the server?

Comment: I'm not using a database, I take strings by file_get_contents from Yandex site

Comment: can you share some code? ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: I've shared some code, hope can be useful

Comment: if `json_decode` doesn't give you any error, then the contents of `file_get_contents` was utf-8 encoded. let's do some debugging: what's the output of `urlencode($syn)`?

Comment: the result is modernit%E3%A0 for one of these synonyms

Comment: I got it... I forgot to say I was using mb_strtolower on those strings. Replacing it with strotolower the problem is solved... Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to say I was using mb_strtolower on those strings. Replacing it with strotolower the problem is solved... Sorry